# How To Make Checkbox Continuos Ajax Php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```js
functions variable functions variable
<!-- js -->

var today = new Date();
  var date = new Date();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var months = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
  var data = {};
  //to pre-check checkboxes, use this format.
  //var data = {'Wed Jul 01 2009':true,'Thu Jul 02 2009':true};
  var checkBox = $("<input type='checkbox'/>");
  var checked1 = false;
 
  function fillCalendar(){
    month = date.getMonth();
    year = date.getFullYear();
    var offset=date.getDay();
    var clone;
    var checked = false;
    $("#month").text(months[month]);
    $("#calendar .day").each(function(i){
      $(this).removeClass("today");
      if(offset+date.getDate()-1==i){
        checked = (data[date.toDateString()])?true:false;
        $(this).html(date.getDate());
        clone = checkBox.clone().attr("title",date.toDateString()).prependTo(this);
        if(checked)clone.click();
        if(date.toDateString() == today.toDateString()) $(this).addClass("today");
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
      } else {
        $(this).html("");
      }
    });
    date.setMonth(month);
    date.setFullYear(year);
    $(".day input:checkbox").unbind("click").click(function(){
      var title = $(this).attr("title");
      if(this.checked){
        data[title] = true;
      } else {
        delete data[title];
      }
      return true;
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectAll").click(function(){$("#calendar input:checkbox").each(function(){
      if(checked1==this.checked) this.click();
    });checked1=!checked1;return false;});
    $("#calendar .selectRow").click(function(event){
      var checked2 = !$(event.target).parent().parent().find("input:checkbox")[0].checked;
      $(event.target).parent().parent().find("input:checkbox").each(function(){ if(this.checked!=checked2)this.click();});
      return false;
    });    
    $("#prevMonth").click(function(){date.setMonth(date.getMonth()-1);fillCalendar();});
    $("#nextMonth").click(function(){date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1  );fillCalendar();});
    $("#done").click(function(){
      var theForm = $("#theForm");
      $.each(data, function(key, val){
        theForm.append("<input type='hidden' name='dates[]' value='" + key + "'>");
      });
      theForm.submit();
    });
    
    date.setDate(1);
    fillCalendar();
  });
```

```css
my style table for this calendar format
<!-- style.css -->

table { width: 400px; }
.top { background-color: #C0C0C0; }
.leader { background-color: #D7D7D7; }
.days { background-color: #EDEDED; }
.today { background-color: #909090; color: #FFFFFF; }
.button { width: 48px; }
.wideButton { width: 98px; }
td { width: 50px; height: 25px; text-align: center; }
```

```html
index page form index page form 
<!-- index.php -->

<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    die();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="#" id="theForm">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" id="calendar">
<tr class="top">
<td><input type="button" class="button" id="prevMonth" value="<" /></td>
<td colspan=2 id="month">&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="button" class="button" id="nextMonth" value=">" /></td>
<td colspan=2><input type="button" value="Select All" class="wideButton" id="selectAll"></td>
<td colspan=2><input type="button" value="Done" class="wideButton" id="done" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="leader">
<td></td>
<td>Sun</td>
<td>Mon</td>
<td>Tue</td>
<td>Wed</td>
<td>Thu</td>
<td>Fri</td>
<td>Sat</td>
</tr>
<tr class="days" id="test">
<td class="leader"><input type="button"value=">>" class="selectRow button" /></td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="days">
<td class="leader"><input type="button"value=">>" class="selectRow button" /></td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="days">
<td class="leader"><input type="button"value=">>" class="selectRow button" /></td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="days">
<td class="leader"><input type="button"value=">>" class="selectRow button" /></td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="days">
<td class="leader"><input type="button"value=">>" class="selectRow button" /></td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="days">
<td class="leader"><input type="button"value=">>" class="selectRow button" /></td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="day">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="leader" colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="renew" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to make my checkbox ajax php cannot skip date.
For example i checked 5.02.2015 and cannot check 7.02.2015
only can check 6.02.2015 in continuos..

Comment: why you are using checkbox name as date format?

Comment: it just my example..

Comment: share actual codes(Part of code instead of whole coding) that's generate problem, including what you have tried. And try to describe more clear what you have tried and what you want to achieve.

Comment: actual code have been shared